# Command to restart and run all in Google Collab?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, runtime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following code in Google Collab that, when run manually, requires me to restart and run manually due to the snowflake libraries.

However, I want to wrap up code that includes this snippet and run it on GCP.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
!pip install snowflake
!pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.3.7
!pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/v2.3.7/tested_requirements/requirements_36.reqs
import snowflake.connector as snow
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
!pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
```

How can I get Google Cloud applications to have this library and be able to run the above script in one pass? And if I can't do that, is there a way to restart and run all via the command?

https://cloudblog.withgoogle.com/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are likely looking for is Google Cloud Functions for your Python.  In setting up a cloud function to run, you upload the code and the libraries, so that they are already installed when you want to execute the function.  Take a look at this guide, as its very complete and detailed:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python